# str_detect find a word that starts with a character and end with a character

Tags: r, regex, stringr

```
library(stringr)

words <- c("proposition", "proper", "poor", "paul", "park", "car")
words[str_detect(words, "^p")]
[1] "proposition" "proper" "poor" "paul" "park"
words[str_detect(words, "r$")]
[1] "proper" "poor" "car"
```

I've significantly scaled down the data of my assignment.

I want to detect words that starts with p and ends with r. I'm expecting proper and poor in the result. I am trying to figure this out for hours now for an assignment.

```
words[str_detect(words, "[^p][r$]")]
```

This comes out anything with p and r in the word regardless of the position.

```
words[str_detect(words, "^pr$")]
```

This thing straight up doesn't work. It doesn't match anything but didn't throw an error. I'm not understanding why it doesn't throw an error though. I first thought it matches the word ^pr$ but doesn't that need an escape "\"?

Comment: If `^` is the first character in character class `[...]`, it negates the whole thing, so `[^p]` looks for anything that *isn't* `p`. Nor does order matter in a character class, so `[r$]` will match either `r` or `$`, which is not what you want. Removing the classes and adding a wildcard `.` repeated 0+ times `*` to expand to capture anything in between, you have `^p.*r$`.

Comment: A useful tool to show what it's doing: https://regex101.com/r/U5O2pu/1 At that site you only need single \ escaping instead of double (\\\) like in R, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there

```
words[str_detect(words, "^p\\w*r$")]
#[1] "proper" "poor"
```

We account for the characters in between `"p"` and `"r"` with `"\\w*"` which translates to any word character occurring `>=0` times.

As @wp78de points out, the word characters matched by `"\w"` include numbers and underscore (think of it as shorthand for `"[A-Za-z0-9_]"`), so if you want to match only characters (upper and lower case) you can do

```
words[str_detect(words, "^p[A-Za-z]*r$")]
```

Comment: I'm crying now. It works. I'm not sure why \w wasn't in my lecture but in my assignment. I looked up \w and it seems to match any words. I get it now!! Thank you.!!

Comment: No worries @ColtonPan, glad it helped; good luck with your assignment;-)

Comment: It might be worth to mention that the `\w` word character matches also numbers and uppercase letters and underscore, eg. `p00r` & `pA_r`.

Comment: I noticed some other answers that worked too used + instead of * after the "any word" class.  Is there any difference?

Comment: @ColtonPan `"+"` requires the preceding pattern to be matched at least once (`>=1`) whereas `"*"` requires the preceding pattern to be matched `>=0`. So `"p[A-Za-z]*r"` will match `word = "pr"` whereas `"p[A-Za-z]+r"` will not.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Got it. Thank you! I think \w* works the best with my assignment. I learned a lot from all the people.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest option is to use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) range: `[a-z]`

```
library(stringr)
words <- c("proposition", "proper", "poor", "paul", "park", "car")
words[str_detect(words, "^p[a-z]+r$")]
```

If you also want to include uppercase letters I would suggest switching on the case-insensitive [inline mode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html):

```
words <- c("proposition", "proper", "Poor", "paul", "park", "car")
words[str_detect(words, "(?i)^p[a-zA-Z]+r$")]
#[1] "proper" "Poor"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `str_detect`, you can also use `str_subset`, which is more concise.

```
str_subset(words, "^p[A-Za-z]*r$")
# [1] "proper" "poor"
```

Answer (score 0):

For this example, you can simply use `.*` to specify any character.

```
words <- c("proposition", "proper", "poor", "paul", "park", "car")
str_subset(words,'^p.*r$')
```